# How to find the minimum value of function like this?

Tags: inequality

Given $x, y, z$ is a positive real number and $x^2+y^2+z^2\le3x$, find the minimum value of $P=\frac{4}{(x+2)^2}+\frac{1}{(y+1)^2}+\frac{8}{(z+3)^2}$

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h533662p3055753,

Comment: @prime2357 I solved your problem. If you want to see my solution, show please your attempts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Cauchy-Schwarz:

$$(x+2y+2z)^2 \leq 3(x^2+4y^2+4z^2)=12(x^2+y^2+z^2)-9x^2\leq 36x-9x^2\leq 36$$

and thus

$$x+2y+2z \leq 6$$

Using AM-GM:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{4}{(x+2)^2}+\frac{1}{(y+1)^2}+\frac{8}{(z+3)^2} &= \frac{4}{(x+2)^2}+\frac{1}{(y+1)^2}+\frac{4}{(z+3)^2}+\frac{4}{(z+3)^2}\\
&\geq 4\sqrt[4]{\frac{4^3}{(x+2)^2(y+1)^2(z+3)^2}}\\
&=\frac{16}{\sqrt{(x+2)(2y+2)(z+3)}}\\
&\geq \frac{16}{\left(\frac{x+2+2y+2+2z+6}{4}\right)^2}\\
& \geq 1
\end{aligned}
$$

Equality happens when $(x,y,z)=(2,1,1)$.

Comment: thank you very much =)))